# mod_wsgi not using venv

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to setup a Django project using Apache with mod_wsgi.
I have set wsgi like this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess Breath python-home=/var/www/vhosts/Breath/env/
WSGIProcessGroup Breath
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/Breath/BreathAlessio/wsgi.py process-group=Breath
```

So I'd like to launch the wsgi.py with the version in the venv, but by checking the version I see it runs it with the default python installation.

I get this error on apache error log because it uses the wrong version.

```
[Thu Apr 07 12:57:09.681861 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 60865:tid 139865656153856] [remote 131.114.215.254:45334] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Apr 07 12:57:09.681898 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 60865:tid 139865656153856] [remote 131.114.215.254:45334]   File "/var/www/vhosts/Breath/BreathAlessio/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Thu Apr 07 12:57:09.681905 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 60865:tid 139865656153856] [remote 131.114.215.254:45334]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Apr 07 12:57:09.681950 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 60865:tid 139865656153856] [remote 131.114.215.254:45334] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have tried to set all the permission to 777 and to change the owner of the project but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, seems like django is not installed on your virtual environment.

I would advice you watch this video, if you follow the steps in the tutorial everything should work and you will see where you did wrong.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=13

Comment: As I have written it's using the default python version and not the one of the venv.

Comment: In fact if I activate the venv and do `python manage.py check` everything works as intended